# How to create an Android App Bundle equivalent to multiple APKs with assets of different size?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android game that is built into multiple APKs, each having the same graphics assets but in different sizes. The graphics assets are in the `assets` directory. Each APK targets certain screen sizes and densities.

I have spent a few hours trying to figure out how to create an App Bundle that would be equivalent to my current multiple APKs. I guess I could use Dynamic Feature Modules and load one at runtime after checking the screen size and density, but I'd prefer Play Store handling the APK distribution completely. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can have all your different assets in a single project and generate an app bundle instead of an apk. You upload the app bundle to the PlayStore and it decides what resources to bundle in an apk depending on the user's device.

I found an interesting article on Medium that details how to work with AppBundle. You can check it out here: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-6c65ce8105a1

Comment: Yes, that's how App Bundles work. You can put different sized resources into their own subdirectories under the `res` directory, e.g. `res/drawable-xhdpi`, and the generated APK for the end user will contain only resources suitable for the end user's device. I am asking whether there is an equivalent mechanism for the `assets` directory, as I haven't found any info so far.

Comment: Oh, OK I understand. As far as I know there is no such mechanism for the assets directory. DFM seems the way to go.